# Make an element "Land" in position when page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When my page loads I want to make my logo fade in and move like 20-30px from down to up at the same time.  I have this code to make it fade in, and is working perfect:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#logo').fadeIn(2000);
});
```

```css
    #logo {
      width: 80%;
      max-width: 650px;
      padding-top: 50px;
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
```

```html
<img id="logo" src="assets/img/mainlogo.png" style="display: none" />
```

But I could really use some help to make it move.  I read a lot about make JavaScript to add a new class or Id to the element so that class have a different padding top or margin top but I can't make it work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: you can use jQuery Animate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

```
("#logo").css("padding-top", "15px");
```

to your "document ready" function.

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp